# Getting two time ajax callback result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".apply").click(function(){
            idd = this.id;
            fname = $("#fname").val();
            company_name = $(".company_name_"+idd).val();
            phone = $("#phone").val();
            alert(fname);
            alert(company_name);
            alert(phone);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"fname":fname, "company_name":company_name, "phone":phone},
                url:"get_data.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#search").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    $sql = "select * from company";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo "<input type='text' name='company_name' class='company_name_".$rows['id']."' value='".$rows['company_name']."'/>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='".$rows['id']."' class='apply'>click me</a>";
    }
?>

<?php
    $query = "select * from login where id = '".$ids."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $row['fname']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>"/>
<?php
    }
?>
```

In this code I have create an ajax jquery script where I am using onclick function. Now what happen when I click on

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='".$rows['id']."' class='apply'>click me</a>
```

Ajax callback two time i.e. it alert the value two times but I want one time. I don't know why? So, How can I fix this issue?

Thank You

Comment: may anyone help me out

Comment: are you getting the correct values in all the alert?

Comment: yes, @YashParekh

Comment: your code looks perfect. try writing the script at the end of the file (mostly after php)...